# redhat repo is not accessible for RHEL 7.6 for sap and RHEL 7.7 for sap (pay-as-you-go) on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rhel7

Redhat repo is not accessible for RHEL 7.6 for sap and RHEL 7.7 for sap (pay-as-you-go) on GCP. I can understand 403 error. But this should not happen on pay-as-you-go Instance on GCP. Below is the Output:

```
$ sudo su -
[root@instance-1 ~]# yum update
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                        |  14 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                        | 4.7 kB  00:00:00     
google-cloud-sdk/signature                                                                  |  454 B  00:00:00     
google-cloud-sdk/signature                                                                  | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
google-compute-engine/signature                                                             |  454 B  00:00:00     
google-compute-engine/signature                                                             | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com/pulp/repos/content/e4s/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.7/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.



 One of the configured repositories failed (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Update Services for SAP Solutions - Optional (RPMs) from RHUI),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=rhui-rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rhui-rpms ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
       will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable rhui-rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rhui-rpms
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=rhui-rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rhui-rpms

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=rhui-rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rhui-rpms.skip_if_unavailable=true
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhui-rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rhui-rpms: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com/pulp/repos/content/e4s/rhel/rhui/server/7/7.7/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
```

Anyone facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in multiple accounts but it was not working. Looks like that after my this post someone from google acted quickly. Now I am able to access the RHEL repositories.

Thanks